# ngSlimScroll is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, slimscroll

I am using ngSlimScroll for scrollbar.Its taking scrollbar height not correctly. once after scrolling down,its not scrolling up/not able to scroll again. 
i have created a directive for scroll bar, i,e slim-bar> and 'g-address>' contains one more directive which fetch records from database. i am using ng-repeat for displaying records. below are my codes.

```
return {

    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class=" profile-user-info-striped" ng-transclude ng-slimscroll color="#0072a0"' +
                   ' height="250">' +
                    '</div>'
};
```

i used below code in my tpl file.

```
slim-scroll>

    g-address ng-repeat="address in aboutCtrl.addresses" address="address">

    /g-address>
/slim-scroll>
```

Please suggest me where its going wrong.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this?

Comment: are you passing the height to slimscroll somewhere?

Comment: yes. height='250'. ng-repeat is creating issue. dont know how to overcome this.